# input text file (a double quoted string w/ %e %i sqrt z1 z2 log) into sympy or numpy or scipy for a Laurent series

Tags: string, file, numpy, sympy, series

Lengthy title, but I thought it might be best to be very informative...

I have very long expressions using symbols such as %i, %e, log, z1 and z2, that is sandwiched in between double quotes, e.g. something like,

```
"(4*z1*z2*%e^(z2^2+z1^2)*((%e^z1^2-%e^z2^2)^2*(96*%e^(13*(((-(202907687053026635*%i*sqrt(1037*sqrt(23)*%i+1463)*(log(9)*sqrt(2)*sqrt(7)*sqrt(1037*sqrt(23)*%i+....."X
```

(where when viewing the file in a hex editor, the last X is not an X but a hexadecimal 0A - whatever that is - don't think looking it up on an ascii chart will shed much light on it)

I'd like to try out the python/sympy/numpy/scipy/... amalgamations in lieu of other CAS-capable software, but I am having no luck finding out how to do this, at least from a consistent "package". I see snippets from a tutorial on scipy, or a snippet from numpy, etc.

I would like to take the Laurent series of an expression like above - it is exact expression devoid of floats.

Hope this is easy to understand request,

Best wishes.

**edit - update Python to 3.6 - still AttributeError**

So I saw some errors in converting the symbols exp, etc. into an acceptable string. This seems to work better *but* "ex" is still not being treated as a *Sympy expression* after sympify:

```
(py3_kernel) sbh@sbh-MacBookPro ~ $ ipython
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 08:44:35) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sympy as s

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: from numpy import *

In [4]: from sympy import *

In [5]: from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify, implemented_function, lambdastr

In [6]: with open('c.txt', 'r') as myfile:
   ...:     d=myfile.read().replace('\n', '').replace('%i','I').replace('%e','exp').replace('^','**
   ...: ').replace('exp**','exp')
   ...:     

In [7]: d
Out[7]: '"(4*z1*z2*exp(z2**2+z1**2)*sqrt(1037*sqrt(23)*I+1463))+log(1/2)+(sqrt(-I)*z1)/(sqrt(3)*23**(1/4))"'

In [8]: z1,z2 = s.symbols('z1,z2', real=True)

In [9]: ex = s.sympify(d)

In [10]: ex
Out[10]: '(4*z1*z2*exp(z2**2+z1**2)*sqrt(1037*sqrt(23)*I+1463))+log(1/2)+(sqrt(-I)*z1)/(sqrt(3)*23**(1/4))'

In [11]: type(ex)
Out[11]: str

In [12]: ex.subs({z1:0, z2:1})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-63eab202c7b1> in <module>()
----> 1 ex.subs({z1:0, z2:1})

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.loadtxt()` is generally used to read tabular data from text files into Numpy arrays. It may be better to use Python to read your file into a string variable and then convert it to an Sympy expression using `sympy.sympify()`.
Suppose I have a file `cal.txt` that contains a one-line string `z1^2*exp(z2)*%i`. The following lines would read it and convert it into a Sympy expression.

```
import sympy as s

with open('cal.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    d=myfile.read().replace('\n', '').replace('%i',\
                 'I').replace('^','**').replace('"','')


z1,z2 = s.symbols('z1,z2')

ex = s.sympify(d)

ex2 = ex.subs([(z1,0),(z2,0)])
```

For this to work `cal.txt` should contain a valid Sympy expression.

**Update**:

1. I modified the content of my file `cal.txt` to `"z1^2*exp(z2)*%i"` and now I also get the same `AttributeError`. So we need to strip the `"` before and after your strings for `sympify` to work properly. I have modified the code above to `replace('"','')` double quotes to null. Hope this will work.
2. In the code above, if we replace the line `z1,z2 = s.symbols('z1,z2')` with `z1,z2 = s.symbols('z1,z2', real=True)`, the `ex2 = ex.subs([(z1,0),(z2,0)])` line will not give desired output because of the `assumption` we have specified on `z1` and `z2`. So we need to be careful when specifying assumptions on our symbols when using `sympify`. The source of this information is "Turning strings into expressions" section of [this](https://mattpap.github.io/scipy-2011-tutorial/html/basics.html) link.

Comment: sorry, %e is just e, as in %e^3 = e^3;  %i is the imaginary number; and I do realize a^b should be a**b for python-y things but then again, I would like to avoid doing hex editing on almost a hundred files...  Can't i just do another .replace(' ^', ' **') also?

Comment: I guess I believe you but I can't see that it works because when I try to do something simple, e.g. ex.subs({z1:0, z2:4}), I get back that `'str' object has no attribute 'subs'` - I still think ex is not something I can "work" with yet...?

Comment: I ran the code in Spyder3 and it seems to work for me. `ex` is a Sympy expression object. What version of Sympy and Python are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.7.12 and sympy 1.1.1 (python2 because a huge software i use requires it)   I added some information to my question when I tried to use python3 and 1.1.1 sympy

Comment: Sorry, I had a meeting to attend. I have copied my output in my answer and it works fine. I am unable to pin-point why we have a difference of results.

Comment: Seems like you nailed it! Thanks for sticking it out for this question!

Comment: I like Python :-). Thank you for giving feedback. Well, it almost works. There is a small problem still that the final `subs` does not give the correct answer, if you noticed.

Comment: You're right - missed that... But https://mattpap.github.io/scipy-2011-tutorial/html/basics.html gave me the idea of adding "from sympy import *" and "var('z1,z2')", and thereafter subs worked fine. Not sure which, or if both did it.

Comment: Great! I was trying to find a fix too. I will keep this trick in mind when using `sympify` in the future. I will add it to my answer just in case someone else finds it useful.